# Как решить проблему с раскладкой при использовании pyautogui?

Tags: python, pyautogui

При использовании библиотеки **pyautogui** столкнулся с такой проблемой.
Имеем скрипт

```py
os.system('chrome.exe')
time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.hotkey('win', 'up')
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'l')
pyautogui.write('https://ya.ru', 0.05)
```

Открываем бразуер, разворачиваем на весь экран и в строке поиска пишем адрес.
Этот код работает отлично если перед запуском скрипта установлена ENG раскладка. Если же нет
то в строке адреса печатается абракодабра. Пробовал вставлять

```py
pyautogui.hotkey('win', 'space')
```

Переключение срабатывает, но проблема не решается.

Есть мысли в чем может быть дело?

Comment: >>> with pyautogui.hold('win'):
        pyautogui.press(['space'])

Comment: извините. не работал с этим pyautogui, но попробуйте так